# Script to ping every hour and email failure

Tags: shell, scripting, ping

I'm trying to write a shell script to ping 5 hosts I have once every 1 hour and if it receives any failure from any of those hosts, it sends an email alert with the results from this failing ping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
    #!/bin/bash

ping_targets="server1 server2 server3 server4 server5"
failed_hosts=""

for i in $ping_targets
do
   ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      if [ "$failed_hosts" == "" ]; then
         failed_hosts="$i"
      else
         failed_hosts="$failed_hosts, $i"
      fi
   fi
done

if [ "$failed_hosts" != "" ]; then
   echo $failed_hosts| mailx -s "Failed ping targets" email@domain
fi
```

Put it in a script, change the hostnames and email address, make it executable, and add an entry to cron so it runs once per hour.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I had to make some modification but your script worked great!!