# Debugging Ping script

Tags: shell, scripting, ping

I asked [before for help with a ping script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345630/script-to-ping-every-hour-and-email-failure) that should ping some hosts and email me if it any ping fails. This works fine.

Now I want to modify that script (see below) so it emails me if it succeeded only. So basically I want the script to ping few hosts I know they're not up and if any of those hosts returned ping, then I want the script to email me. Here's the script I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

ping_targets="server1 server2 server3 server4 server5"
failed_hosts=""

for i in $ping_targets
do
   ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      if [ "$failed_hosts" == "" ]; then
         failed_hosts="$i"
      else
         failed_hosts="$failed_hosts, $i"
      fi
   fi
done

if [ "$failed_hosts" != "" ]; then
   echo $failed_hosts| mailx -s "Failed ping targets" email@domain
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

ping_targets="server1 server2 server3 server4 server5"

for i in $ping_targets
do
   ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "$i ping success!" > test_file
   fi
   if [ -s test_file ];then        
         mailx -s "Successful ping targets" -a test_file email@domain
   fi
```

If you don't want to add attachment, replace `mailx` line with:

```
mailx -s "Successful ping targets" email@domain < test_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ping_targets="server1 server2 server3 server4 server5"
up_hosts=""

for i in $ping_targets
do
   ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      if [ "$up_hosts" == "" ]; then
         up_hosts="$i"
      else
         up_hosts="$up_hosts, $i"
      fi
   fi
done

if [ "$up_hosts" != "" ]; then
   echo $up_hosts| mailx -s "ping targets that are now available" email@domain
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Use fping to check ping of multiple servers:

```
fping server{1,2,3,4,5} |& grep -v 'is alive' | mailx -E -s "Failed ping targets" email@domain
```